# Pre-populated inputs not recognised on mobile devices

Tags: input, textarea

I have created some javascript that pre-populates an input and textarea with details from the users account in my Wordpress site.  These are hidden while the select boxes show "No" and appear for the user to edit when they click "Yes".

This works on my desktop computer using Chrome and Edge but mobiles do not recognise the pre-populated contents of the input and textarea until you have physically clicked and entered some text.

```
// Javascript to pre-populate niche and writing sample inputs. 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Fetch the user's 'niche' value via AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'get_user_niche'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // If the response is not empty, set the input value
            if(response) {
                $('input[name="NICHE"]').val(response);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch the user's 'writing_sample' value via AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'get_user_writing_sample'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // If the response is not empty, set the textarea value
            if(response) {
                $('textarea[name="WRITING_SAMPLE"]').val(response);
            }
        }
    });
});

// Javascript to control visiblity of niche and writing sample as the select values change

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Initially hide NICHE input and WRITING_SAMPLE text area containers
    $('input[name="NICHE"]').closest('.mwai-form-field.mwai-form-field-input').hide();
    $('textarea[name="WRITING_SAMPLE"]').closest('.mwai-form-field.mwai-form-field-textarea').hide();

    // Listen for changes on EDIT_NICHE select box
    $('select[name="EDIT_NICHE"]').change(function() {
        var nicheContainer = $('input[name="NICHE"]').closest('.mwai-form-field.mwai-form-field-input');

        if ($(this).val() === 'Yes') {
            nicheContainer.show();
        } else {
            nicheContainer.hide();
        }
    });

    // Listen for changes on EDIT_WRITING_SAMPLE select box
    $('select[name="EDIT_WRITING_SAMPLE"]').change(function() {
        var writingSampleContainer = $('textarea[name="WRITING_SAMPLE"]').closest('.mwai-form-field.mwai-form-field-textarea');

        if ($(this).val() === 'Yes') {
            writingSampleContainer.show();
        } else {
            writingSampleContainer.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried using this:

```
var $input = $('input[name="NICHE"]');
$input.val(response).trigger('input');

var $textarea = $('textarea[name="WRITING_SAMPLE"]');
$textarea.val(response).trigger('input');
```

and this:

```
// For the 'NICHE' input
$.ajax({
    // existing code ...
    success: function(response) {
        if(response) {
            var $input = $('input[name="NICHE"]');
            $input.val(response);
            $input.focus().blur();
        }
    }
});

// For the 'WRITING_SAMPLE' textarea
$.ajax({
    // existing code ...
    success: function(response) {
        if(response) {
            var $textarea = $('textarea[name="WRITING_SAMPLE"]');
            $textarea.val(response);
            $textarea.focus().blur();
        }
    }
});
```

But no joy, I still need to click in the input and textarea, add some text before it will recognise any of it.